# Extract a string between two letters and create a new column in R dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, stringr

I have a data.frame that looks like this

```r
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- tibble(genes=c("AT1G02205","AT1G02160","AT5G02160", "ATCG02160"))
df1
#> # A tibble: 4 × 1
#>   genes    
#>   <chr>    
#> 1 AT1G02205
#> 2 AT1G02160
#> 3 AT5G02160
#> 4 ATCG02160
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

and I want to extract anything between the letters `A` and `T` and create a new column so my new.df looks like

```
#>   genes         chr
#>   <chr>    
#> 1 AT1G02205     Chr1
#> 2 AT1G02160     Chr1
#> 3 AT5G02160     Chr5
#> 4 ATCG02160     ChrC
```

So far, I have found a nasty way to do this, but I am sure I could have done better.

````
``` r
library(tidyverse)
df1 <- tibble(genes=c("AT1G02205","AT1G02160","AT5G02160", "ATCG02160"))

new.df <-  df1 |> 
  mutate(chr=str_extract(genes, "T(.*?)G"))  |> 
  mutate(chr=str_replace_all(chr, c("T"="", "G"=""))) |> 
  mutate(chr=paste0("Chr",chr))
new.df
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   genes     chr  
#>   <chr>     <chr>
#> 1 AT1G02205 Chr1 
#> 2 AT1G02160 Chr1 
#> 3 AT5G02160 Chr5 
#> 4 ATCG02160 ChrC
````

<sup>Created on 2022-10-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str_match`:

```r
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(chr = str_c("Chr", str_match(genes, "T(.*)G")[, 2]))

#   genes     chr  
# 1 AT1G02205 Chr1 
# 2 AT1G02160 Chr1 
# 3 AT5G02160 Chr5 
# 4 ATCG02160 ChrC
```

Or in base R with `gsub`:

```r
df1 |>
  transform(chr = paste0("Chr", gsub(".*T(.*)G.*", '\\1', genes)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `base R`

```
df1$chr <-  with(df1, sprintf("Chr%s", substr(genes, 3, 3)))
df1$chr
[1] "Chr1" "Chr1" "Chr5" "ChrC"
```

Comment: This is so so cool! and just one line